# Unable to redirect to home page after facebook login in spring security login application

Tags: spring-mvc, authentication, spring-security, facebook-login

I have implemented spring security in my application for authentication the user.
Its working fine for me.
Now i want to add facebook login to my application. I have implemented it. its giving proper response. **When I login with credentials using spring login it redirects to home page, But when I use facebook login button(it displays message "Thanks for logging in, Kuldeep Singh!") control remains on same login page. I want it to redirect to home page as it redirects in case of spring login.**

Second problem after logged in by facebook, button still shows the 'log in', I guess after login it should be changed to 'logout'.

If any body has any solution, please let me know.

Thanks
Kuldeep

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to register a JavaScript callback on the login page https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/v2.2

```
// In your HTML:
<input type="button" value="Login" onclick="FB.login();">
<input type="button" value="Logout" onclick="FB.logout();">

// In your onload method:
FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', login_event);
FB.Event.subscribe('auth.logout', logout_event);

// In your JavaScript code:
var login_event = function(response) {
  console.log("login_event");
  console.log(response.status);
  console.log(response);
}

var logout_event = function(response) {
  console.log("logout_event");
  console.log(response.status);
  console.log(response);
}
```